# PyCurl - error with libcurl

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl, pycurl

I am using pycurl - actually wants to use it - in my python scripts.
I install it pip install pycurl - it pull version 7.43.0

When executing `import pycurl` I have error 'Incompatible library version: pycurl.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0'

I check - latest stable version of libcurl is 7.19.0

What I am doing wrong. 
- I am using Mac with 10.10.5

Answer (score 0):

I have installed pycurl just like you with `sudo pip install pycurl` and get `Successfully installed pycurl-7.43.0`, after which `import pycurl` is ok. and my `libcurl.4.dylib` is provided with version 8. I would recommand remove libcurl, and reinstall it with pycurl, refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/24890).